# Strip spaces when inserting a record into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table in Rails with just one column called `:name`. When inserting a record into this table, I would like to strip all the spaces from the text and change it to upper case. Where would i write this method — in the Model file? What method would I have to override? When inserting data into this Model, I'm using a method called `find_or_create_by_name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [ActiveRecord callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html). It might look like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :strip_and_upcase_name

  def strip_and_upcase_name
    self.name.strip!
    self.name.upcase!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. BTW, what does the exclamation mark after `strip` and `upcase` signify?

Comment: @Mridang - A method ending in an exclamation point is a convention in Ruby to signify some sort of destructive operation. In this case it means that these methods alter the value of `self` instead of returning a new string with the changes. This particular example is the equivalent of doing this: `self.name = self.name.strip.upcase`

Comment: One minor nitpick: I would rename the method to 'strip_and_upcase_name', to clearly signify that only the 'name' attribute is being transformed.

Comment: I would advise against chaining the ! methods, because they return nil when they don't modify anything. If you have a string without any spaces to strip, you will be calling upcase! on nil, thus raising a `NoMethodError`.

Try `name = name.strip.upcase` or call each ! method in its own line.